# Running bash cmds within Java

Tags: java, bash, command-line, google-api

I'm trying to run a bash cmd that grabs infomation from the google api using my api key. I run the code in the terminal and I get the output that I want (which is the address alone). But when I try use the call within java it doesnt work. I believe it ends up being a null call.

The cmd is as follows:
"wget -O- -q "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=4-chōme-2-8 Shibakōen, Minato City, Tokyo 105-0011, Japan&key=[MY_API_KEY]"|grep '"formatted_address"'|cut -d\: -f2

This is my current java code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Process runtime = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wget -O- -q \"https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=4-chōme-2-8 Shibakōen, Minato City, Tokyo 105-0011, Japan&key=[MY_API_KEY]\"|grep '\"formatted_address\"'|cut -d\\: -f2");
    Show_Output(runtime);
}
public static void Show_Output(Process process) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader output_reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String output = "";
    while ((output = output_reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Desired output is:
"4-chōme-2-8 Shibakōen, Minato City, Tokyo 105-0011, Japan",

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73774587/edit) the question to show the actual code, with the command included and the output

Comment: Also why run that command? All the steps it does could be implemented in Java

Comment: @hardillb oh, I had no Idea please do tell :)

Comment: Whoever chose to close this issue has at least used an incorrect question as "duplicate". The issue here is not whitespace or anything, but what I described in my answer - multiple commands treated as a single command.

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate as it's merely a problem of having spaces and quotes in the command. See my answer in the dupe. But as hardillb says, you should use an HTTP client class of some sort instead of wget. HTTP connection is a solved problem in Java.

Comment: @RealSkeptic it's not caused by spaces and quotes, it's 3 commands treated as one.

Comment: @rob - both, I think. You could solve the multiple commands issue by using bash directly, but it won't solve the spaces issue if you just throw the command at it. In any case the root of the problem is not understanding that calling a command from Java is not like calling it from the command line in bash.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes, you're probably right about the spaces. `Runtime.exec` is pretty bad when it comes to spaces in arguments, `ProcessBuilder` is much better.

Answer (score 2):

With the `Process` class you can only execute a single command. You on the other hand have 3:

- wget -O- -q "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=4-chōme-2-8 Shibakōen, Minato City, Tokyo 105-0011, Japan&key=[MY_API_KEY]"
- grep '"formatted_address"'
- cut -d: -f2

I see 4 options:

1. create a shell script that contains these commands, and execute that
2. create 3 processes (one for each command), and chain their input / output streams.
3. use a process only for the curl command, and perform the grep and cut in Java
4. skip using commands completely, and just use Java for the entire thing

I'd personally go for option 4. With Java's own [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) this should be pretty straight forward.

- use `HttpClient` to get the response as a string
- use `response.lines()` to get a stream of lines
- use `filter` to replace `grep` (`.filter(line -> line.contains("..."))`)
- use string manipulation to replace `cut`

Comment: Wow I had no idea that was a thing. Thank you thank you :)